# Prevent jQuery Datepicker from highlighting the whole week

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jQuery [datetimepicker](https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker)

JavaScript code:

```js
$('#from_date').datetimepicker({});
```

HTML:

```html
<input type="text" id="from_date"/>
```

The datepicker is working as expected until I select a date: it is highlighting the whole week.

CDN used for datepicker

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.css

Current O/P

[image]

Here I have selected date 25 but the whole week is getting highlighted.

Expected O/P

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution by my-self.

Basically, I was missing on parameter.

```
formatDate:'DD.MM.YYYY',
```

[formatDate](https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/#formatDate) worked for me.

```
$('#from_date').datetimepicker({
   formatDate:'DD.MM.YYYY',
});
```